# Changing VS2010 text formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatting

I am looking for a c# formatting which will do(like in Eclipse):

```
f(){
}
```

instead of

```
f()
{
}
```

I have checked tools->options formatting but could not find it.

Comment: I know its all down to personal preference, but it appears you like the code laid out as the Java stylistic convention uses. Have you considered writing your C# code as dictated by Visual Studio defaults (and ultimately Microsoft)? It makes it easier for other C# developers to read your code. Also look at using StyleCop, this can be a great help (and a hindrance to some) in writing style conforming code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tools -> Options 
    -> Text Editor 
        -> C# 
            -> Formatting 
                -> New Lines 
                    -> New line options for braces 
                        -> Place open brace on new line for ....
```

There are a few options in there, I'm guessing you're likely wanting to disable most of those. But specifically in this case I believe is for `Place open brace on new line for control blocks`.

In addition, check out the other options for C# in and around there. It's pretty extensive and most likely you'll be able to achieve whatever combination of style you desire.

Comment: That awesome, it worked. Is there any way of putting } after hitting RETURN after {? I mean automaticly add closing bracket,

Comment: AFAIK, not natively within the vanilla Visual Studio installation. However, there are a few extensions that will do that. You can use Joel Spadin's "Brace Completer" (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d) or Microsoft's "Productivity Power Tools" (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/?SRC=Home)

Comment: Thank you, going to check it.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow this: Option -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines

Uncheck all the "New lines option for braces"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > New Lines > Place open brace on new line for control blocks.